# Tensor-flow training and Testing on different OS

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

Will the performance of the model be affected if I train the data on LINUX system and then use that model in the WINDOWS application or a python script?

Comment: Not sure about Windows, but i frequently train on Linux and restore/use the saved model on Mac. No problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the model will be exactly the same. You'll only have to make sure that your TF versions on Linux and Windows are compatible ones, but this is not made more difficult by the different OS, it's only a matter of which versoin you install on which device.

Answer (score 0):

Akshay, as gdelab said, make sure about the version. If you are running the same model on same data(training and testing) again & again, it might affect but using on different OS might not. I faced the same issue.